# Improper operand type

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2013

```
mov dword ptr [0b26180h], edi // error C2415: improper operand type
```

Why is this an improper operand type? AFAIK x86 does support this kind of addressing. Machine code was 89 3D 80 61 B2 00. Am I using the wrong syntax for Visual C++ inline assembly?

Comment: Well that's weird. It should be supported, the syntax is OK (I think?), and yet it indeed refuses to assembly it. To make matters weirder, the reverse (`mov edi, dword ptr [0]`) works just fine.

Comment: How about `mov dword ptr ds:[0b26180h], edi` ?

Comment: Are you using x64 mode ?

Comment: Inline asm isn't supported in x64 mode. ds:[0b26180h] works but isn't ds supposed to be the default?

Comment: @XTF when you use the `ds:[0b26180h]` syntax, does that fix this for you ?

Comment: @XTF  Okay, then I believe I may have discovered your mental block: the phrase "*supposed to be*".  Those guys had a lot to think about, and this one slipped by them.